# How to pass the parameters from view to controler in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

My jsp contains of  two radio buttons upload and delete. and when i select my delete radio button two date picker(start_date and end_date) columns will be visible. how can we pass these parameters from view to controller in spring mvc. when upload is selected the data will get added to mysql  database. when we select the delete option and we give the start date and end date the records belonging to the particular date alone get deleted from the database. i dono how to pass those parameters from view to controller. can any one please help me in this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass like normal input field and get @RequestParameter in Controller.
http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/07/accessing-request-parameters-using.html#.VVCG4reN194